# Can't add iOS application icons in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: ios, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I have Xamarin.Forms project and want to add iOS application icons. So I've created Assets Catalog, but when I open it I can't add any icon:

[image: Visual Studio]

I'm using VS 2015 Update 2 and the latest Xamarin version.
I found a video of how it should work: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KZbrLwJwGeE
I have no clue why I can't add any icons, any help is appreciated.

Mine Contents.json looks like this:

```
{
 "images": [],
  "properties": {},
 "info": {
  "version": 1,
  "author": "xamarin"
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue in the Xamarin plugin for VS.

In VS, delete all your asset catalogs.
Open your solution in Xamarin Studio Mac. Add an asset catalog. Double clic the .json file in Resources / Images.xcassets / AppIcons.appiconset / and it will open a working editor. Put your icons there. Save the solution.

You can now reopen the solution in VS. Never edit the asset catalog in VS again until this is fixed (could be many months).

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to check the `Contents.json` for AppIcons it might be corrupt? it will be in `Images.xcassets`>`AppIcons.appiconset`>`Contents.json` it should look like this :

```
{
  "images": [
    {
      "idiom": "iphone",
      "size": "29x29",
      "scale": "1x"
    },
    {
      "idiom": "iphone",
      "size": "29x29",
      "scale": "2x"
    },
    {
      "idiom": "iphone",
      "size": "29x29",
      "scale": "3x"
    },
    {
      "idiom": "iphone",
      "size": "40x40",
      "scale": "2x"
    },
    {
      "idiom": "iphone",
      "size": "40x40",
      "scale": "3x"
    },
    {
      "idiom": "iphone",
      "size": "57x57",
      "scale": "1x"
    },
    {
      "idiom": "iphone",
      "size": "57x57",
      "scale": "2x"
    },
    {
      "idiom": "iphone",
      "size": "60x60",
      "scale": "2x"
    },
    {
      "idiom": "iphone",
      "size": "60x60",
      "scale": "3x"
    },
    {
      "idiom": "ipad",
      "size": "29x29",
      "scale": "1x"
    },
    {
      "idiom": "ipad",
      "size": "29x29",
      "scale": "2x"
    },
    {
      "idiom": "ipad",
      "size": "40x40",
      "scale": "1x"
    },
    {
      "idiom": "ipad",
      "size": "40x40",
      "scale": "2x"
    },
    {
      "idiom": "ipad",
      "size": "50x50",
      "scale": "1x"
    },
    {
      "idiom": "ipad",
      "size": "50x50",
      "scale": "2x"
    },
    {
      "idiom": "ipad",
      "size": "72x72",
      "scale": "1x"
    },
    {
      "idiom": "ipad",
      "size": "72x72",
      "scale": "2x"
    },
    {
      "idiom": "ipad",
      "size": "76x76",
      "scale": "1x"
    },
    {
      "idiom": "ipad",
      "size": "76x76",
      "scale": "2x"
    },
    {
      "idiom": "car",
      "size": "120x120",
      "scale": "1x"
    },
    {
      "size": "24x24",
      "idiom": "watch",
      "scale": "2x",
      "role": "notificationCenter",
      "subtype": "38mm"
    },
    {
      "size": "27.5x27.5",
      "idiom": "watch",
      "scale": "2x",
      "role": "notificationCenter",
      "subtype": "42mm"
    },
    {
      "size": "29x29",
      "idiom": "watch",
      "role": "companionSettings",
      "scale": "2x"
    },
    {
      "size": "29x29",
      "idiom": "watch",
      "role": "companionSettings",
      "scale": "3x"
    },
    {
      "size": "40x40",
      "idiom": "watch",
      "scale": "2x",
      "role": "appLauncher",
      "subtype": "38mm"
    },
    {
      "size": "44x44",
      "idiom": "watch",
      "scale": "2x",
      "role": "longLook",
      "subtype": "42mm"
    },
    {
      "size": "86x86",
      "idiom": "watch",
      "scale": "2x",
      "role": "quickLook",
      "subtype": "38mm"
    },
    {
      "size": "98x98",
      "idiom": "watch",
      "scale": "2x",
      "role": "quickLook",
      "subtype": "42mm"
    }
  ],
  "info": {
    "version": 1,
    "author": "xcode"
  }
}
```

You could try to edit the xml manually with a text editor to set the filename like so :

```
{
  "filename": "icon-29.png",
  "size": "29x29",
  "scale": "1x",
  "idiom": "iphone"
},
```

`icon-29.png` will then have to be added to the folder `AppIcons.appiconset` but from your comment I think it will wipe it out again, I think this is a bug and would file it here https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/

Comment: Mine Content.json is almost empty, see question update.
I've replaced it with your version, but it didn't help. After VS restart, the changes were reverted.

Comment: Hmmm that doesnt seem right, I feel it may be a bug, from looking at this thread on Xam.forumshttps://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/11503/images-xcassets-in-visual-studio/p2  its a new feature for VS to support Asset Catalogs. I would file a bug for it. I could add a version of Contents.json with an image set but i think it will wipe it out again.

Comment: Same problem, my app doesn't deploy properly from VS to simulator. Everything compiles fine but the app crashes immediately because of a resource not found. It seems that PDF assets are not deployed. Works fine from Xamarin Studio.